# URL is appended to WSGI script's path, why?

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have a development server set up running Apache 2.2 with mod_wsgi. I have a test project and a webapp in development setup, and they half work. When I attempt to access something other than the project's landing page, Apache appends the rest of the URL onto the path of the WSGI script and won't load the page.

In httpd.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAplias /dubserv/ /home/sli/www/dubserv.wsgi
<Directory /home/sli/www/dubserv>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

When accessing something other than the landing page for the app, this is the result (in this case, /login/):

```
[Tue Aug 24 12:38:44 2010] [error] [client 192.168.1.100] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /home/sli/www/dubserv.wsgilogin
```

The result is the same if I put the WSGI script in anywhere under the project's root.

Comment: Can you paste your WSGI conf too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use /dubserv and not /dubserv/ with WSGIScriptAlias. The instructions shouldn't show a trailing slash and so one should not be included.